# react redux: containers composition

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am building an React+Redux application, I come to the point where I am
considering to use a container inside another container. I am asking myself if
this is a good approach, ie. is it good practice, or should we strictly follow the rule of 1 container with several components ?

Comment: Why do you need container inside a container?

Comment: The question is simply related to Encapsulation, which is super important programming concept. Knowing how to use containers within containers in Redux lets programmers to write applications which scale and composed of really reusable components. Also, this is the only way to understand how to use Redux without React's setState().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let me quote [Dan Abramov's article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.x3fzuuj8a) about presentational- and container- components:

> When you notice that some components don’t use the props they receive but merely forward them down and you have to rewire all those intermediate components any time the children need more data, it’s a good time to introduce some container components. This way you can get the data and the behavior props to the leaf components without burdening the unrelated components in the middle of the tree.

...meaning it is perfectly fine to have a container component inside another container component if you feel the need for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to find which component should stay "dumb" and which component should be aware of application and become a container. I don't think it's a problem / anti-pattern to use a container in another one. If a part of your application is used on different pages it can be a container, be connected and use in differents pages/containers, Just be aware : this "container component" will specific to this application