# Create React/Redux containers using AOP?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on React/Redux web app. We have simple components and Redux-aware containers, say Header and HeaderContainer. The problem is that we have to use HeaderContainer instead of Header wherever we need to use it.

It usually get more complicated when we have to [use a container inside a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450350/react-redux-containers-composition). That is a component which is supposed not to know about Redux, should reference a container which uses Redux.

Is there anyway to register HeaderContainer to be used instead of Header, wherever it is used?

Comment: Can you give an example of what `HeaderContainer` is and what it is adding to `Header`? Redux's `connect` returns a container by default.  Why do you need an *extra* container?

Comment: @DavinTryon HeaderContainer is what `connect` returns. The problem is that now I need to use HeaderContainer instead of Header.

Comment: If the name is the problem, you could rename `HeaderContainer` to `Header` and then rename `Header` to something internal.

Comment: References should be replaced, not only the names. With AOP you can inject additional behavior into existing components.

Comment: The closest you are going to find is Higher-Order Components for AOP.  That is why I was saying, that `connect` is already a HOC.

Comment: HOC is not directly comparable to AOP. With AOP you can inject additional behavior (such HOCs) into existing components "without changing the existing code". For example you can register HeaderContainer to be used instead of Header without changing Header or other components which use it.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think you are confusing IOC (Inversion of Control container) with AOP (Aspect-Oriented Programming). :)  Higher Order Components allow the creation of *decorators*.  Decorators could be considered a type of aspect (or mixin).

Comment: Yes, you are somehow mistaken. With AOP you can inject additional behavior into existing code while existing code is not aware of them. But in IOC/DI the existing code expects those additions. Anyway HOC is neither, because it does not add new behavior into existing components, but it return a "new" component which includes those additions and then it is you responsibility to use the new component instead of the origin.